# Dash Plotly Graph (Dash core component throwing error)

Tags: plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

[error image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtPXt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw16V.png)
Hello everyone,

I am trying to use the basic example given for dash to plot graph but it is throwing this error in the screenshot. I do not really know what the problem is. Does anyone know if the das core components for plotting graph has changed or something?

This is the link to where I got the code. https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components [enter link description here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components)

The error said "Dash design kit could not be resolved"
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is how the code look like.

import dash
import dash_design_kit as ddk
import dash_core_components as dcc

dcc.Graph(
    figure=dict(
        data=[]
     )
)

Comment: Did you try simply dropping the line `import dash_design_kit as ddk`?

Comment: Hi @Michel, Thanks for your question. I did not just drop the line only. I actually have import dash, then import dash_design_kit as ddk and then continued.

Comment: I just copied and pasted as found here [link](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components). I noticed any example involving `dash-design-kit` core components does not work for me while the rest do so far. Is it because I am only using my design account for free? @Michel

Comment: I have never used `dash-design-kit` myself, but the code you've shown should work without it.

Comment: Thank you @Michel. The particular project require `dash-design-kit` but it is not working, but for this one it worked with it. I don't know why. I have not use `dash-design-kit` before too. Any further advice?

Comment: I haven't used `ddk` either, so I can't give anymore advice. Sorry! From what I gather though, it is indeed not part of the free version of Dash (see [here](https://plotly.com/dash/design-kit/)).

Comment: Thank you @Michel for the clarification. How do I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples on the site you linked should work without `dash-design-kit`, so you could simply drop the import for them to work.

If your code depends on actually using `dash-design-kit`, it is not part of the free Dash installation, but part of Dash Enterprise (see [here](https://plotly.com/dash/design-kit/)). The error should disappear after acquiring and installing Dash Enterprise.